# Normalization of Descendants

Tags: conformal-field-theory

How are descendants of a primary operator normalized in a CFT with $d>2$? If the primary operators are normalized as $\langle\Delta|\Delta\rangle=1$ then how are the descendants normalized? On the first level, the normalization is $2\Delta$. Is there any recursion relation for the normalization on a higher level?

Comment: How does $\langle\Delta|\Delta\rangle=1$ normalize operators, rather than just vectors? How does it relate to a $2\Delta$ normalization?

Comment: This question only makes sense if you precise your definition of the norm. For instance how do you deal with Lorentz indices? (if $\Delta$ is a scalar its first descendant is a vector)

Answer (score 2):

The recursion relation is just the conformal algebra, since norms are computed by moving the Ps past the Ks in
\begin{equation}
\left < \Delta, R | K_{\mu_n} \dots K_{\mu_1} P_{\mu_1} \dots P_{\mu_n} | \Delta, R \right >.
\end{equation}
It looks like there would be many obstacles to getting an explicit formula. Not the least of which is that descendants are most usefully organized into irreps of $SO(d)$ and writing down a full set of projectors for this group is quite involved. Notably, https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05551 gave a formalism for doing this.